# react js material.ui and redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

Hello I have doubts about how I will populate my card with data that I will receive from my store

I have a reducer using thunks to get data from my backend, but I don't know how I could get her states using this structure for ui

my card ui component

```
import React from "react";
// nodejs library that concatenates classes
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

// @material-ui/core components
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
// @material-ui/icons

// core components
import styles from "../assets/cardStyle";

const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

export default function Cards() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div>
            <Container fixed>
                <Grid container direction="row" >
                    <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Card className={classes.card}>
                            <CardContent className= {classes.cardCarousel}>
                                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                                    This impressive paella is a perfect party dish and a fun meal to cook together with your
                                    guests. Add 1 cup of frozen peas along with the mussels, if you like.
                                </Typography>
                            </CardContent>
                        </Card>

                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
}
```

my action:

```
import {FETCH_FAIL,FETCH_LOADING,FETCH_SUCESS} from './actionType';
import api from '../../../services/api';

const FetchSucess = data = () => ({
    type:FETCH_SUCESS,
    data
});
const FetchFailed = error = () => ({
    type:FETCH_FAIL,
    error
});
const isLoadingFetch = () => {type: FETCH_LOADING}

export const getAllProducts = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(isLoadingFetch);
        api.get('/products')
        .then( response => { dispatch(FetchSucess(response.data));})
        .catch( err => { dispatch(FetchFailed(err.message));});
    }
}
```

my reducer :

```
import {FETCH_FAIL, FETCH_SUCESS, FETCH_LOADING} from '../../actions/fetch/actionType';

const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    products: [],
    filteredProducts: [],
    fn:[],
    mw:[],
    ft:[],
    ww:[],
    bs:[],
    stattrek:[],
    normal:[],
    error: null
  };

  export default function productReducer(state = initialState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
      case FETCH_LOADING:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: true
        };
      case FETCH_SUCESS:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: null,
          filteredProducts: action.data.listProducts,
          products: action.data.listProducts,
          fn: action.data.fn,
          mw: action.data.mw,
          ft: action.data.ft,
          ww: action.data.ww,
          bs: action.data.bs,
          stattrek: action.data.listProducts.filter(value=> value.id_types === 1),
          normal: action.data.listProducts.filter(value=> value.id_types === 2)
        };
      case FETCH_FAIL:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: action.error
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

my reducer config:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );
}
```

my api return this:

```
async getAllProduct(req,res){
    try {
        const results = await Products.findAll({
            // raw: true, <= remove
            attributes:['id','name', 'float', 'price','img_product', 'description'],
            include: [{
                model: SubCategory,
                as: 'subcategory',
                attributes: ['id','name'],
            },
            {
                model:Exteriors,
                as: 'exteriors',
                attributes: ['id','name']
            },
            {
                model:Types,
                as: 'types',
                attributes: ['id','name']
            },
        ],
        })
        console.log(results);
        let listProducts= results.map( (products) => {
            return {
                id: products.id,
                name: products.name,
                float: products.float,
                price: products.price,
                id_sub: products.subcategory.id,
                subcategory: products.subcategory.name,
                id_types: products.types.id,
                type: products.types.name,
                id_ext: products.exteriors.id,
                exterior: products.exteriors.name,
                img: products.img_product,
                description: products.description
            }
        })

        const fn = listProducts.filter(v => v.id_ext == 2)
        const mw = listProducts.filter(v => v.id_ext == 3)
        const ft = listProducts.filter(v => v.id_ext == 1)
        const ww = listProducts.filter(v => v.id_ext == 4)
        const bs = listProducts.filter(v => v.id_ext == 5)

        if(listProducts){return res.status(200).json({listProducts,fn,mw,ft,ww,bs})}
        else{return res.status(400).json({result: 'failed to get Products'})}
     } catch (error) {
         console.error(error);
     }
},
```

I would basically need to use connect and get the states from my store

but I don't know how I could achieve this in this structure

Comment: You shared your store configuration, but not your reducer. It's impossible for an outsider to infer your store structure from that, we'd need the actual reducer.
Also, it would be interesting to know the structure of data returned by the API.

Oh, and slightly related: that's a function component. You can use the useSelector hook, no need to connect. Connect is only required for class components.

Comment: @phry omg my bad 
i thought i put the reducer sorry

i added my backend return and my reducer

Comment: Using function will I have any disadvantages regarding using classes?

Comment: No, functions can achieve everything class components can (except error boundaries, but that shouldn't concern you very often) and hooks are a much more modern way of writing react.

In your case, I'm not 100% sure what you want to achieve, but let's say you want to access `mw` from your Component, then you can just do
`useSelector(state => state.products.mw)` to access it (assuming your root reducer puts your `productReducer` on the key `products`, you didn't share that one.)